# how to write file with node webkit js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-webkit

When I build my app, 'fs' module doesn't work. So, it must write file, but when I start my app nothing happens. But if I start my app with:

```
$ /path/to/app nw
```

It works correctly. What's wrong?

Some code, where I use fs:

```
function check_prob_2(){
    console.log('Problem 2');
    fs.appendFile('log.txt', 'Checking problem 2: \n\n');
    ...
    }
```

I use that function, but it doesn't work. It doesn't work only after build application. I build it with  [this guide](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)

Comment: Try using this path `./log.txt`

Comment: @Alesfatalis I replaced 'log.txt' with './log.txt', but still doesn't work.

Comment: Well than webkit.js works different than i thought. Try Renzos answer it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Include the following (standard) module:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Specify the path as follows:

```
fs.appendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './log.txt'), 'Checking problem 2: \n\n');
```

More info on the __dirname global can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

**EDIT**

Since __dirname is not defined in node-webkit, you'll have to use the following workaround:

Make a file `util.js` or however you want to call it, containing this line:

```
exports.dirname = __dirname;
```

The __dirname variable can now be exposed in your main file:

```
var dirname = require('./util.js').dirname;
```

And replace `__dirname` by `dirname` in the code.

Details [here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Changes-related-to-node#__dirname)

Comment: It says: __dirname is not defined
But if I run it 
$node app.js
It works, is it troubles with nwjs?

Comment: It appears node-webkit doesn't expose __dirname. You'll have to use a workaround, see my edited answer