# Why do __filename / __dirname behave weirdly after minifying with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs

Can some one shed any light on this weird issue i've been having.

I have a project of the following shape:

```
index.js

src/
    static/
        favicon.ico
        styles.css
    server.js
    routes.js
    app.jsx
    //[...]

dist/
    /static
        favicon.ico
        styles.css
    server.js
```

The `/src` dir gets compiled (via webpack) and uglified out into a `/dist` dir. The `index.js` in the root project directory is just a simple switch that requires `/dist/server.js` if `NODE_ENV=production`, and reqiures `/src/server.js` if in development.

The issue i'm having is that `__dirname` and `__filename` behave as expected when running in development --- correctly reporting the directory *each* executed file is in. However, when running in production, the only directory getting reported is the root directory where `index.js` is. `dist/server.js` does not seem to recognise that it's inside a `/dist` folder, it seems to now think it's inside the project root. Weird!!

What's happening here? Why does the minified `dist/server.js` think it's nested *within* `./index.js`, but the non minified `src/server.js` correctly recognises its within the `src/` dir?

Is this webpack/uglify transforming things it shouldn't, or is this just the nature of minified code running in production? I'm struggling to find a work around, which is making setting `dist/static/` as the correct static dir in production rather difficult.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I bet it's due to the way stuff in the minified js is defined/executed. The code is no longer part of that file and instead run "outside", which causes it to appear as if it'd be in the root.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This might actually be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090842/webpack-can-not-use-dirname), which also contains a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to the webpack conf fixes the issue. It appears as if webpack mocks __dirname by default resulting in just a `/`. True compiles __dirname to a string of the context path, and false leaves `__dirname` how it is in node.

```
  node: {
    __dirname: false  
  },
```

Cheers to Mario in the comments above for pointing me in the right direction!