# ES6 get path of module inside module

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

How can i get moudle path inside module? I use babel and webpack to create bundle for ***browsers***.

I expect

/src/someModule/index.js

```
console.log(`someModule path is ${process.execPath}`);
```

**to output in *browser*** `someModule path is /home/user/proj/src/someModule`

or `someModule path is /src/someModule`

Comment: When running JS in a browser, you can't have any information on the server, since it is ran locally by the client's browser. Why do you need that information ? Maybe you are missing something, or haven't found a proper solution to a problem you have.

Comment: yes it is, but can i get this paths during webpack processing as strings in final bundle like webpack plugin DefinePlugin to pass process.env to bundle?

Comment: You can try `module.i` and `module.children`. This worked in my React app.

Comment: @Andrew what is the problem you are trying to solve? Currently it looks like you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to access the module path inside an ES6 module (yet). This is a [known problem](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/nodejss-filename-dirname-in-es6-modules), and there's a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) for a new meta property `import.meta` that resolves to an object with the respective information. Read more about that [here](http://2ality.com/2017/11/import-meta.html).

That said, the webpack bundler *does* [support Node's `__dirname`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/), see e.g. [Current file path in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553868/1048572) or [Webpack can not use __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36090842/1048572).

Comment: As of writing this, things have progressed and various browsers now implement import.meta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta#Syntax

Answer (score 12):

The [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta#Syntax) is now supported in all modern browsers, yay!

```js
// /es6/someFile.js
console.log(import.meta);
```

Outputs:

```
{url: "https://yourdomain.com/es6/someFile.js"}
```

(even though OP asked about webpack, I believe this info will be useful for many people coming here)